# Change C++ model with QML

Tags: c++, qml

I want to extend the example called "Object ListModel Example" from Qt documentation
(you can get it on http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/declarative-modelviews-objectlistmodel.html).

I am trying to add a simple GUI functionality: a menu item that changes the content
(i.e. name) of the first data item in the model. Something like this:

```
MenuItem {
  text: "Item 123"
  onClicked: {
    myModel.setProperty(0,"name","Item 123") //this gives me error
  }
}
```

I am able to create a menu in QML but I cannot find the correct way to make changes in the model.

Btw, what is a difference between setContextProperty and qmlRegisterType (only the first one is used in this example but many other examples include the second one).

Comment: If you ask a question that, basically, states "this gives me an error", then you should probably include _what_ error you get. Just copy-paste any error messages directly into the question.

Comment: Thanks for answer and comments. I have also asked a more specific question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091495/access-items-of-qstandarditemmodel-from-qml) and with the help of all answers now I understand the problem better. Please note, that on the mentioned link I have added my working solution on how to change data of QStandardItemModel from QML. Well, there I didn't use user roles as desired in this question but the given code is therefore even more usable to the beginners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That kind of model is really not suitable for modification.  There is no way for the view to be notified of changes.  A better option is to use a QAbstractItemModel: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/declarative-modelviews-abstractitemmodel.html

A simpler way to use a QAbstractItemModel is via QStandardItemModel: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstandarditemmodel.html

setContextProperty() adds a single named property to the context.  qmlRegisterType() registers a QObject-derived type with the QML engine, allowing it to instantiate that type.  For example, the QDeclarativeItem type is registered with the engine as "Item", which is how the engine knows what to create when `Item {}` appears in QML code.

Comment: Now, I also tried with "AbstractItemModel Example" from Qt documentation. But I get exactly the same error: **TypeError: Result of expression 'myModel.setProperty' [undefined] is not a function**.

Comment: You need to implement the setProperty() slot in your model.

Comment: Thanks. I decided to go with QStandardItemModel. But I am still lost without an example. How to access items of QStandardItemModel from QML? Is there another (better) way of changing data from QML instead of setProperty()?

Comment: @meolic Just add a QINVOKABLE method to the model, and return your item pointers from there (be sure to read docs on cppOwnership, etc, and also beware that tricks like returning a base class ptr may not work (you'll get that exact undefined message in qml), returning QObject pointers works, though).